# Ask Different needs correct tags for 'Mac OS X Server' (10.0 - 10.6) and 'OS X Server (10.7 - 10.9)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, suggested-edits

IMHO there is something wrong with the now available **OS X Server** tags!
When I did some extensive re-taging edits on the 'OSX-Server' tagged Questions I realised that people would mostly not adhere to the given meaning of the [tags-wiki](http://Apple.StackExchange.com/tags/osx-server/info) but actually to the naming convention that Apple has chosen for its products.

As of now, Apple calls it "OS X Server" and the App to manage the Server is called Server.app <-- So, one is the App and the other is the Server System itself.

If then added the core (Mac) OS X system version name tag (e.g. #Mavericks), we get the full picture of which Operating System we are talking about.

[image: Add OS X Server to OS X Mavericks]

---

But what about the old Mac Server System versions from Apple?

Well, they were called **Mac OS X Server** 10.x and the Software to manage the Server was called 'Server Admin' and 'Workgroup Manager'.

---

### tags needed for 10.0 - 10.6

```
- Mac-OS-X-Server (the full Mac Server Version)
- Server-Admin.app
- Workgroup-Manager.app
```

---

### tags needed for 10.7 - 10.9

```
- OS-X-Server (as an add-on to an installed OS X) 
- Server.app
```

Comment: As you can see, I sugest to change even to change the existing tag, so it would be easier to migrate to the new tags. I would help to do the massive work of re-tagging.

Comment: Let's keep the discussion on the original thread. We don't need any work on retagging, as the moderator tools probably can automate the task once we've got enough votes on your suggestion there.

Comment: Great Disappointment for me. I dont feel taken serious!

Comment: @b,ike You saw that I did greatly rewrite my post and deleted the original Answer? did you?

Comment: Why would you delete your answer and then repost here? Let's keep the discussion on server tags on one thread.  Also - things can take a week to a month to get sorted out. Are you perhaps just being impatient? Let me know what you want. I can reopen this, but that will likely slow the effort to form consensus.

Comment: @bmike because it is a meta discussion to be done. It is way broader than your original Question. And as told before: I did not repost my Answer. I took my text and invested some serious time to edit it and then posted a starter post for a real discussion. Yes it looks very similar, BUT it is not. And it is here because it is not an answer to your original Question. I had not the courage in the first place to put it as a new discussion. And I can wait ... (see my Question about my WebDAV Server Problem)

Comment: Have at more discussion. Cheers and thanks for explaining what you wants the post to be.

Comment: Please do a little research how our users use the Server related tags. e.g. The wiki had been visited 40 times and nobody saw the nice grammar typo (for 2 years). I'm serious about this. Nobody cares about how some admins set the tags meaning. They just use it as they like.

Comment: @josh-k what's your view on this discussion?

Comment: @tony-williams Hi, as a main contributor to the OSX-Server topic, I would like to read or see your vote on this very discussion. THX for your time.

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity I suggest what the tag wikis currently say.

- Sever.app for 10.7 and up where you just instal the app on top of normal OSX.
- OSX-server for 10.6 and below where you need a license key and separate install media to install the sever build instead of the client/workstation build of OSX.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I sugest using the old tags and give them the proper meaning and just add one new tag:

---

### tags for Mac OS X Server 10.0 - 10.6

```
- Mac-OSX-Server (new tag for 'Legacy' full Mac Server Versions)
- ServerAdmin
- Workgroup-Manager.app
```

---

### tags for OS X Server 10.7 - 10.9

```
- OSX-Server (as an add-on to an installed OS X) 
- Server.app
```